# Change MSN chat status icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, msn, msn-messenger

I'm using this tip to integrate MSN Messenger to my Website: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3987-integrate-msn-chat-on-your-website-or-blog
It shows an icon with the current MSN status (online, away and so on). I want to change these images. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I made a snafu answering this the first time:

Going here:

http://messenger.services.live.com/users/XXXXXXXXXXX@apps.messenger.live.com/presenceimage?mkt=en-GB

will redirect you to:

http://www.wlmessenger.net/static/img/presence/Offline.gif

which makes detecting the status a whole lot easier!

I missed that.

---

I looked here:

http://settings.messenger.live.com/Applications/CreateHtml.aspx

I picked the Status Icon option, and was given code like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://settings.messenger.live.com/Conversation/IMMe.aspx?invitee=XXXXXXXXXXX@apps.messenger.live.com&mkt=en-GB">
    <img style="border-style: none;"
     src="http://messenger.services.live.com/users/XXXXXXXXXXX@apps.messenger.live.com/presenceimage?mkt=en-GB"
     width="16" height="16" />
</a>
```

<strike>The path to the image remains the same no matter what your status.</strike>

There is no way to change the image based on which status is returned in the image with pure HTML/CSS/JS (afaik). (even after I realised it redirects)

I can think of a technique to do it, <strike>but it's *not easy*</strike> and it's *not too hard*, but you'll have to use a server side language such as PHP or ASP.NET.

You would change that code to something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://settings.messenger.live.com/Conversation/IMMe.aspx?invitee=XXXXXXXXXXX@apps.messenger.live.com&mkt=en-GB">
    <img style="border-style: none;" 
     src="proxyMyMsnImage.php"
     width="16" height="16" />
</a>
```

`proxyMyMsnImage.php` would do the following things:

- Does a `HEAD` request (or `GET`, if that doesn't work) on the image (`http://messenger.services.live.com/users/XXXXXXXXXXX@apps.messenger.live.com/presenceimage?mkt=en-GB`)
- Depending on which image you're redirected to (for example `Offline.gif`), you send your own version of that status image, along with the correct mime type, for example `image/gif`.
- You could cache the results of this, and only update it if at least X time has passed (say, 2 minutes).

Figuring out how to detect which status image you were sent is <strike>the most difficult part</strike> now really easy.